# Using Linq Aggregate or ForEach to update properties for a running total

Tags: c#, linq, aggregate, cumulative-sum

I have a class with an integer property.  I have a list of them that are to be used in a charting application.  I want to display this property as a cumulative total, while retaining all of the other class information.

Let's call this class ProgressMeasurement and the property is OutstandingItems.  Is there some method, using the Aggregate function where I can accomplish this?

For example:

```
progressMeasurementList.Aggregate((a, b) =>  b.OutstandingItems += a.OutstandingItems));
```

i.e.  I want to update `b`'s OutstandingItems value to be the current running total.

Cheers

Comment: Are you saying you want to update the property of the items in the list with the running total?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing built in but you can create your own extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<TAccum> Scan<T, TAccum>(this IEnumerable<T> seq, TAccum init, Func<TAccum, T, TAccum> op)
{
    TAccum current = init;
    foreach(T item in seq)
    {
        current = op(current, item);
        yield return current;
    }
}
```

You can then calculate a sequence of cumulative sums as:

```
var runningTotals = progressMeasurementList.Scan((acc, b) =>  acc + b.OutstandingItems));
```

Comment: @gabba Because the idea of `Aggregate` is to generate one single value from using a combining operation on all of the values in the sequence.  He doesn't want to generate a single value, he wants to generate a new sequence of values, so it just doesn't apply.

Comment: -1 This does not address the question of setting the running total to the property of each item.

Comment: You are right. But he wants to update sequence not to make new collection.

Comment: @gabba Then he shouldn't be using LINQ at all.  If you *do* want to use LINQ, then this is *exactly* how it should be done.  Given the mutually exclusive goals in the question you need to pick one, and Lee choose to use LINQ rather than choosing to mutate the variables without LINQ, as others did.  Those are the two correct options.

Answer (score 1):

Linq is for *querying*, not *updating*.  Updates are typically cleaner with traditional loops:

```
var runningTotal = 0;
foreach(var item in progressMeasurementList)
{
   runningTotal += item.OutstandingItems 
   item.OutstandingItems = runningTotal));   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That would be the `.Sum()` method:

`var sum = progressMeasurementList.Sum(prog => prog.OutstandingItems);`

Comment: That would give me a complete total, not a running total.

Answer (score 0):

I would do that in a `foreach`.  Linq queries shouldn't be used to change the source.

```
var runningTotal = progressMeasurementList.First().OutstandingItems;
foreach(var progressMeasurement in progressMeasurementList.Skip(1))
{
    runningTotal += progressMeasurement.OutstandingItems;
    progressMeasurement.OutstandingItems = runningTotal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe to late but Iam add aggregate variant of this

```
    int total = 0;
    t.Aggregate(total, (acc, current) =>
        {
            acc+= current.OutstandingItems;
            current.CumulativeOutstandingItems = acc;
            return acc;
        });
```

note: I don`t know you want to replace OutstandingItems with cumulative sum or not. I put sum in different property just for readability.

Comment: 1) the whole point of using `Aggregate` is that it holds onto a total for you, you don't need to create your own.  That's what `acc` is here. 2) It's generally best to avoid side effects in LINQ operations; it's designed for *querying*, not modifying data.

Comment: 1. in this example this holds total to use in update.
2. you completely right

Comment: 1) and I'm saying you don't need to.  It already exists and the `Aggregate` method is creating the variable, updating it as needed, and providing it to you for use in your method (providing you use the appropriate overload).  Using a closure in this way is...undesirable.  It's actually a *lot* harder to demonstrate that it works, and it's much more fragile to changes in environment or usage.

Comment: oh.. you point me to big mistake I make.. there should be no clousers

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `ForEach` method, something like this:

```
int runningTotal = 0;
progressMeasurementList.ForEach(item =>
                                    {
                                        runningTotal += item.OutstandingItems;
                                        item.OutstandingItems = runningTotal;
                                    });
```